# Trying to figure out why git rev-list doesn't behave the way I expect

Tags: git

I have a pair of branches, master and develop, that have a shared history.  I run this to see what commits exist only in develop and not in master:

```
git rev-list --no-merges develop ^master
```

it gives me a list of hashes:

```
2855e2bc0be2b31a1ecc6b1982cb250bce93d160
03c0fa2aa7e7969cd0f0597af3a922a671cbfb67
aa2a8ab2703c648d010377f55ff7e4748e1d9d9a
ee1192481391d4cebaa5787669db985eab445b82
1b02e1f58a464e8f90d13dc61c932cb8cacaec38
ab6b1022f2275e2513c4abf0be9eb8098776771d
0ea538c6791f6581285924c5d95eea929409a834
```

Yay.  I apply the second one of these to master with cherry-pick, like this:

```
git cherry-pick 03c0fa2aa7e7969cd0f0597af3a922a671cbfb67
```

I run my git rev-list again.  And get the same list of hashes.  So far, to be expected.  Then I run git rev-list with a new option:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --cherry-pick develop ^master
```

And I still get the same list.  The page for rev-list says this about cherry-pick:

```
Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the "other side" when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference.
```

Between that description, and the name itself, I had the impression it would omit any cherry-picked commits from the list, but it's not doing that.  What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually using "symmetric difference":

```
   Another special notation is "<commit1>...<commit2>" which is useful for
   merges. The resulting set of commits is the symmetric difference
   between the two operands. The following two commands are equivalent:

               $ git rev-list A B --not $(git merge-base --all A B)
               $ git rev-list A...B
```

(Note: when it says "are equivalent" it's being a little too general; only the three-dot syntax sets the internal flag that causes `--cherry-mark` and `--cherry-pick` to work.)

Anyway, try:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --cherry-pick develop...master # or --cherry-mark
```

You may also want `--left-only` or `--right-only` (you can swap master and develop to change left vs right too, although since it's symmetric, that's purely notional anyway :-) ).

---

It might be nice if one could get git to do this without requiring the literal symmetric difference specification, since sometimes patches get (re-)cherry-picked across merge boundaries.  For instance:

```
-C-o-o-o-o-o-o    <-- branchA
    \     \
-o-o-m-R-o-M-P-o  <-- branchB
```

Here `branchB` has `branchA` merged in twice, at `m` and `M`.  There's a commit `C` on branch `A` that was reverted on `B` at commit `R` (revert)—presumably `brB` was not yet ready for it—then "re-picked" after the second merge `M` made `B` ready for it.  The "restoring" commit, made with an actual cherry-pick, is commit `P` (pick).  You can't get git to compute the "sameness" of `C` and `P` because `branchA...branchB` prunes off `C` as being "below" the two merge bases (at both `m` and `M`).  But as long as you're not looking for that—and `master..develop` suggests you're not—you should be fine.

Comment: This is the second time, in as many days, where you have helped me. This site is great because of users like you. Thanks! Great answer btw.